# Mysql in-time query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm in need of some help structuring in-time queries. There's a few of them I need - but I think that if I can be shown how to do one, I can figure out the others.

What I'm after:
-Rolling 12 month view of 'inactive accounts'...ie number of accounts that have not placed an order in the 12 months prior. 
-This ideally will be a subquery (in a much larger script) joining back on to a dates table (see below)

```
January 2015 | # of customers with no orders from 1/2014-1/2015
February 2015 | # of customers with no orders from 2/2014-2/2015
March 2015 | # of customers with no orders from 3/2014-3/2015
etc...
```

What I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around is how I'd structure a where clause to ensure that it scans all orders and only returns the total of account ID's that had not placed an order in the year prior to that month. I've used different combinations of DATEDIFF, DATESUB etc.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime, '%Y-%m'), COUNT DISTINCT (account_id)
FROM warehouse.orders
JOIN warehouse.accounts ON xyz
WHERE...
```

It feels like I'm on the right path - I just keep mentally going in circles trying to figure this out.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to simply comment on your question. I don't fully understand it though.

Are you using SQLServer/TSQL or MySQL?

Do you want to have just one column which calculates the last 12 months' rolling average or 12 columns for the rolling average each month? If it is just one figures for the last 12 months tolling do you want that to be from the current day or the beginning of that month?

If it was SQL Server and a rolling 12 months to now, the calculation could be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(y,GETDATE(),order_date_time) < 1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT account_id) END) as January2015
```

If you're using MySQL replace GETDATE() with NOW()

If you want one value rolling but to the beginning of the month then you could use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(y,DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, GETDATE()), 0),order_date_time) < 1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT account_id) END) as January2015
```

If I've missed the point entirely, please let me know and I'll happily amend the answer

Comment: Thank you for the help. I thought I had mentioned I'm using MySQL, I guess not. My mistake.

I am looking for one column to join onto, or be grouped into, months - wherein it'll say the total number of customers that have not placed an in the previous year. <br/>
Example:<br/>
January 2015 | 1095<br/>
IE 1,095 of our customers had not placed an order from January of 2014 until January of 2015. 

Now, there'll have to be another where clause ensuring that the created_date doesn't exceed the month in question (as we can't count customers we acquired in 2016 as not having placed an order in 2015)

Comment: No, you had mentioned it in the title, but it was tagged as sqlserver.
I'm a bit closer to understanding your requirement - I was miles off the first time.

Can you please just clarify - do you want to be able to report where there were no orders in the 12 months prior to any month, or just the current month? If you need to be able to report the number of accounts  that didn't place an order during the prior year for any month then it is slightly more complicated as you'll need a calendar table. But both ways are definitely possible.

Comment: I'm looking for a 12 month view for a rolling 12 moths. (mouthfull...)

Basically I have a long script with a bunch of different measures joining to a dates table via: `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(d.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Thus, because the parameters are around curdate(), from the month the report runs it only provides results for the 12 previous full months. For each of those 12 full months I need the number of customers who did not place an order in the year prior to that given month.

Comment: We define inactive as those who haven't placed an order in the given year - so I'm trying to show the number of accounts that 'go inactive' month by month

Comment: Thanks again for all your help by the way

Answer (score 0):

You should query between dates,  in order to get the count of events for each id.

```
 select case 
 when count(account_id)<0 then 'INACTIVE'
 when count(account_id)>0 then 'ACTIVE'
 from warehouse.orders
 where data_format(order_datetime, '%m/%Y') between '1/2014' and '1/2015'
 group by account_id)
```